# Loop through POST fields and set to variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a selection of post fields which are submitted through a web form:

```
$_POST['first_name'];
$_POST['last_name'];
$_POST['house_number'];
$_POST['postcode'];
```

etc

I would like to add the following code structure to each one:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $first_name = mysql_prep($_POST['first_name']);
}
```

How can I use a loop to achieve this to save having to repeat myself multiple times?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) function to do this for you.

```
extract($_POST);
// you now have a variable for every key in $_POST
```

If you only want a certain list of keys, and not the full array, you can also use [`variable-variables`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (a variable with two leading `$`, such as `$$var`):

```
$keysToExtract = array('first_name', 'last_name');
foreach ($keysToExtract as $key) {
    $$key = $_POST[$key];
}
// you now have $first_name and $last_name
```

Comment: @Teneff I'm not looping through `$_POST`, I'm looping through my pre-defined array `$keysToExtract`. The purpose for it is to **only** extract the list of keys specified - not the full `$_POST` array (which `extract` is for).

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_map()  PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for apply some operations for all array elements.

And after that `extract($_POST)` if you want to receive variables with names like `$_POST` array keys.

Answer (score 2):

Try using foreach:

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    $$key = mysql_prep( $value );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
$$key = mysql_prep($value);    
}
```

$$ is setting a variable variable